# Cómo puedo generar imagenes aleatoreas en Angular2+?

Tags: angular, imagen, angular5

Mi lista de elementos es muy grande (más de 900, sin imagen), y necesito poner imagenes a cada uno de ellos (para una presentación), para ello tengo una pagina "https://picsum.photos/?random". Pero usandolo desde *ngFor me genera toda la lista repitiendo la misma imagen, Como puedo generar distintas imagenes para cada elemento?

Comment: Muestranos la parte del código que tienes para obtener las imagenes... Recuerda que StackOverflow es una comunidad de ayuda, para ayudarte mejor tienes que mostrarnos el progreso que has tenido por tu cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con algo así:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of item;let index=index">
    {{item}}
    <img [src]="'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=' + index">
</div>
```

En la pagina te muestran que podés obtener una imagen es especifico con la terminacion `?image=` mas el indice de la imagen que querés.

Ahora que si de verdad querés imagenes aleatorias entonces tenés que conseguir una función aleatoria, hay muchas de esas en internet buscalas.